# Magento 2 : How Blocks are Displayed?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

Why do we call in the `list.phtml` template
`<?php echo $block->getChildBlock('addto')?>` if it is already defined in the Layout. Will not it be rendered only because we have already specified it in the layout. Why also in the template to call it?

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
        ...
       <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" 
       name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
        ...
       </block>
       ...
    </block>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In magento nested blocks were not called directly.

Means if you have block inside block then you have to call `getChildBlock()` to call its child block.

if you dont pass any parameter in `getChildBlock()` method then it will render all its child block.

otherwise it loads only specified child block.

Comment: Thanks. But `getChildHtml()` displays the block, and `getChildBlock()` returns the block object. What for `getChildBlock()` then?

Comment: @EvgeniyKapelko `getChildHtml` will return complete html of that block and `getChildBlock()` will return block object while using `getChildBlock('some blockname')->toHtml()` will return its html